# Modifying tags of an XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm looking for the best way to dynamically modify the tags of a very large XML file.

Consider the following input XML:

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootTag>
   <dictionary>
      <name>field1</name>
      <address>field2</address>
      <gender>field3</gender>
      .
      .
      <postcode>field30</postcode>
   </dictionary>
   <records>
      <record>
         <field id="field1">John</field>
         <field id="field2">Svalbard</field>
         <field id="field3">M</field>
         .
         .
         <field id="field30">12345</field>
      </record>
      .
      .
      <record>
      .
      .
      </record>
   </records>
</rootTag>
```

The XML file contains a dictionary on top and a huge chunk of record nodes, whose tags are linked to the dictionary.

I'd like to replace the **tags** within each record node to their corresponding value from the dictionary. Thus, the output should look like:

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootTag>
   <records>
      <record>
         <name>John</name>
         <address>Svalbard</address>
         <gender>M</gender>
         .
         .
         <postcode>12345</postcode>
      </record>
      .
      .
      <record>
      .
      .
      </record>
   </records>
</rootTag>
```

Keeping in mind that there are a tremendously large number of `<record>` nodes, what's the best way to achieve this transformation in Java?

Note that I only want to change the tags and not the attributes.

Comment: If you said you wanted to build a bridge over a very wide river, I would expect any competent engineer to ask you how wide is very wide? The answer depends: the solution for 100Mb might be different from the solution for 10Gb.

Comment: Fair point. I'm talking about multiple XML files about 200 MB in size.

Comment: 200Mb is possible to handle in memory these days, but it's close to the limit, so you probably want to consider streaming techniques if there's a chance it will get any larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @PeterJaloveczki that xslt could be the way. Following could make the job

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dictionary" />

    <xsl:template match="field">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id" />
        <xsl:variable name="tagName" select="/rootTag/dictionary/node()[. = $id]/name()" />

        <xsl:element name="{if ($tagName != '') then $tagName else 'field'}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*[name() != 'id']" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is simplified in some points because xml examples are also simplified but basically it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably using XSLT would be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with a SAX XML parser, which would make sure you do not load the whole DOM tree at once.

In short, you would first populate a dictionary and then, for each tag, one by one as you parse them, replace its name with whatever dictionary contains.

An example on how to approach SAX paring in Java:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use StAX, it has high performance, it processes xml as stream without loading the whole xml in memory, and it is convenient to use.

Answer (score 0):

SAX Parser is the way to go as it parses the XML as a stream instead of reading it at one shot.
See this for details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not parse the XML manually?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ReplaceTextInXmlTest
{
   @Test
   public void test(
   ) {
      try {

         final String inputXml = new String(
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "<rootTag>\n" +
            "   <dictionary>\n" +
            "      <name>field1</name>\n" +
            "      <address>field2</address>\n" +
            "      <gender>field3</gender>\n" +
            "   </dictionary>\n" +
            "   <records>\n" +
            "      <record>\n" +
            "         <field id=\"field1\">John</field>\n" +
            "         <field id=\"field2\">Svalbard</field>\n" +
            "         <field id=\"field3\">M</field>\n" +
            "      </record>\n" +
            "         <field id=\"field1\">Fritz</field>\n" +
            "         <field id=\"field2\">Hamburg</field>\n" +
            "         <field id=\"field3\">M</field>\n" +
            "      </record>\n" +
            "   </records>\n" +
            "</rootTag>"
         );
         final Map<Integer, String> mapping = new HashMap<>();
         final int start = inputXml.indexOf("<dictionary>");
         final int end = inputXml.indexOf("</dictionary>", start) + 13; // "</dictionary>".length() = 13
         final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         final DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document dom = null;
         try (
            ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputXml.substring(start,    end).getBytes());
         ) {
            dom = db.parse(is);
         }
         final Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
         final NodeList nodes = root.getChildNodes();
         for(int i = 0, z = nodes.getLength(); i < z; ++i) {
            final Node node = nodes.item(i);
            final int type = node.getNodeType();
            if(type == 1) {
               final String name = node.getNodeName();
               final String value = node.getTextContent();
               mapping.put(new Integer(Integer.parseInt(value.substring(5))), name);  // "field".length() = 5
            }
         }

         final Pattern fieldPattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\s*<)field id=\"field([0-9]+)\"   (>[^<]*</)field(>\\s*)$");
         final StringBuilder outputXml = new StringBuilder();
         try (
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(inputXml));
         ) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               final Matcher match = fieldPattern.matcher(line);
               if(match.find() == true) {
                  final int fieldId = Integer.parseInt(match.group(2));
                  final String tagName = mapping.get(new Integer(fieldId));
                  outputXml.append(match.group(1));
                  outputXml.append(tagName);
                  outputXml.append(match.group(3));
                  outputXml.append(tagName);
                  outputXml.append(match.group(4));
               } else {
                  outputXml.append(line);
               }
               outputXml.append('\n');
            }
         }

         final String expectedXml = new String(
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "<rootTag>\n" +
            "   <dictionary>\n" +
            "      <name>field1</name>\n" +
            "      <address>field2</address>\n" +
            "      <gender>field3</gender>\n" +
            "   </dictionary>\n" +
            "   <records>\n" +
            "      <record>\n" +
            "         <name>John</name>\n" +
            "         <address>Svalbard</address>\n" +
            "         <gender>M</gender>\n" +
            "      </record>\n" +
            "         <name>Fritz</name>\n" +
            "         <address>Hamburg</address>\n" +
            "         <gender>M</gender>\n" +
            "      </record>\n" +
            "   </records>\n" +
            "</rootTag>\n"
         );
         Assert.assertEquals(expectedXml, outputXml.toString());

      } catch (final Exception e) {
         Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}
```